# Why are my Ethereum smart contract transactions not showing up after X amount of transactions?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3py, etherscan

I'm testing a very simple contract I made (just has one function that emits a particular event) on the Kovan testnet. Now this works perfectly fine on it's own, however when using web3.py and making many transactions in a short period of time (500 in maybe 5-10mins), only 1/3 of them seem to show up, than it just stops updating ([using this to see contract transactions](https://kovan.etherscan.io/)), note, web3.py throws no error, and interacting with the contract on remix still shows success, however I'm simply unable to see any updates. So I'm just curious if there's any rate limiting, or just a function of Ethereum/smart contracts I'm unfamiliar with that's causing this problem.

Comment: How do you check if your tranasction completes and "shows up"?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa, it'd run my tests (with web.py) to create fake transactions with my smart contract, than check all the transactions my smart contract had received at the website I linked above, but the problem is the disproportion between transactions sent, and transactions that seem to have successfully "shown up"

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same problem, I just jacked up the gasPrice, and switched over to Ropsten testnet.